# Skip list implementation in C

Tags: c, skip-lists

I'm implementating a skip list in C.
However, the skiplist_insert function is not working. The taskArray in the node that is inserted into the list doesn't have the correct tasks.
I really can't figure out why.
Can someone point me to the right direction?
I've been stuck at this for days.

The original implementation is found [here](https://gist.github.com/zhpengg/2873424).
The malloc function is replaced by OSMemCreate and OSMemGet since it's gonna be used on a real time OS which doesn't allow the use of malloc.

This is how I use the code (truncated for simplicity):

```
skiplist_init(&rTaskList);
task recTask = {(period+tickCnt) % MAXTICKCNT,
                  overflow,
                  TCB,
                  name,
                  taskptr,
                  prio,
                  stk,
                  stksize};
  arr.count = 1;

  arr.tasks=&recTask;

  skiplist_insert(rTaskList, 0, arr);
```

This is the implementation itself

```
typedef struct task{
  CPU_INT16U period;
  CPU_INT08U overflow_flag;
  OS_TCB * TCB;
  CPU_CHAR * name;
  OS_TASK_PTR taskptr;
  OS_PRIO prio;
  CPU_STK * stk;
  CPU_STK_SIZE stksize;
}task;

typedef struct taskArray{
  CPU_INT32U count;
  task * tasks;
}taskArray; 

typedef struct snode {
    int key;
    taskArray arr;
    OS_MEM  *  MyPartitionPtr;
    OS_MEM * ForwardPartitionPtr;
    struct snode **forward;
} snode;

typedef struct skiplist {
    int level;
    struct snode *header;
} skiplist;

skiplist *skiplist_init(skiplist *list) {
    int i;
    OS_ERR  err;
    CPU_INT08U   MyPartitionStorage[12][100];  
    CPU_INT08U   MyPartitionStorage2[12][100]; 
    OS_MEM      MyPartition; 
    OS_MEM      ForwardPartition;
    // Memory management       
    OSMemCreate((OS_MEM    *)&MyPartition, 
                (CPU_CHAR  *)"My Partition",           
                (void      *)&MyPartitionStorage[0][0],                      
                (OS_MEM_QTY ) 12,                            
                (OS_MEM_SIZE)100,                            
                (OS_ERR    *)&err);


    snode *header = (snode *)OSMemGet((OS_MEM    *)&MyPartition,
                                      (OS_ERR    *)&err);

    list->header = header;
    header->key = INT_MAX;
    header->MyPartitionPtr = &MyPartition; // update mem ptr

    // Replace malloc function
    OSMemCreate((OS_MEM    *)&ForwardPartition,                 
                (CPU_CHAR  *)"My Partition",           
                (void      *)&MyPartitionStorage2[0][0],                      
                (OS_MEM_QTY ) 12,                            
                (OS_MEM_SIZE)100,                            
                (OS_ERR    *)&err);

    header->forward = (snode **)OSMemGet((OS_MEM    *)&ForwardPartition,
                                          (OS_ERR    *)&err);
    if (err != OS_ERR_NONE){
      true; // for catching memory allocation errors
    }
    header->ForwardPartitionPtr = &ForwardPartition; // update mem ptr

    for (i = 0; i <= SKIPLIST_MAX_LEVEL; i++) {
        header->forward[i] = list->header;
    }

    list->level = 1;

    return list;
}

static int rand_level() {
    int level = 1;
    while (rand() < RAND_MAX / 2 && level < SKIPLIST_MAX_LEVEL)
        level++;
    return level;
}

int skiplist_insert(skiplist *list, int key, taskArray arr) {
    OS_ERR  err;
    OS_MEM    MyPartition;
    OS_MEM      ForwardPartition;
    CPU_INT08U   MyPartitionStorage[12][100];  
    CPU_INT08U   MyPartitionStorage2[12][100]; 

    snode *update[SKIPLIST_MAX_LEVEL + 1];
    snode *x = list->header;
    int i, level;
    for (i = list->level; i >= 1; i--) {
        while (x->forward[i]->key < key)
            x = x->forward[i];
        update[i] = x;
    }
    x = x->forward[1];

    if (key == x->key) {
        x->arr = arr;
        return 0;
    } else {
        level = rand_level();
        if (level > list->level) {
            for (i = list->level + 1; i <= level; i++) {
                update[i] = list->header;
            }
            list->level = level;
        }

    //Mem alloc                       
    OSMemCreate((OS_MEM    *)&MyPartition,                 
                (CPU_CHAR  *)"My Partition",           
                (void      *)&MyPartitionStorage[0][0],                      
                (OS_MEM_QTY ) 12,                            
                (OS_MEM_SIZE)100,                            
                (OS_ERR    *)&err);

    x = (snode *)OSMemGet((OS_MEM    *)&MyPartition,
                                      (OS_ERR    *)&err);



    x->key = key;
    x->arr = arr;
    x->MyPartitionPtr = &MyPartition; // update ptr

    // replace malloc function       

    OSMemCreate((OS_MEM    *)&ForwardPartition,                 
                (CPU_CHAR  *)"Forward Partition",           
                (void      *)&MyPartitionStorage2[0][0],                      
                (OS_MEM_QTY ) 12,                            
                (OS_MEM_SIZE)100,                            
                (OS_ERR    *)&err);


    x->forward = (snode **)OSMemGet((OS_MEM    *)&ForwardPartition,
                                        (OS_ERR    *)&err);

    x->ForwardPartitionPtr = &ForwardPartition;
    for (i = 1; i <= level; i++) {
        x->forward[i] = update[i]->forward[i];
        update[i]->forward[i] = x;
    }
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "the skiplist_insert function is not working" okay... would you take some time to describe what isn't working? Perhaps you could share how you call the various function. What you expect to happen. What doesn't meet your expectation....

Comment: @4386427 the snode that is added into the skip list has the correct key, but the arr->tasks is not what I expected. I initialize it with skiplist_init(&rTaskList). Afterwards, I create a task, and a taskArray arr, put arr.tasks=&task, then call skiplist_insert(rTaskList, 0, arr);

Comment: Add that information to the question using the "edit" link

Comment: @4386427 I've added additional information. Thank you for your feedback.